# How do I determine the lens to set the focal length of a converging or diverging beam?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I have a gaussian beam going through two lenses. The first lens is focusing a collimated gaussian beam to a focal point either before or after the second lens.

What formula do I use to get the focal length (the strength of the lens) of the second lens such that the beam, after going through both lenses, focuses at a point "x" after the second lens?

Comment: I'm setting up an experiment but have little knowledge in optics

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247617/how-is-focal-length-defined-for-a-two-lens-system-separated-by-a-distance-d ?

Comment: For the formula, does the total focal length calculated factor in the distance between the two lens?