# How do you derive the formula's for equivalent focal length and back principle plane for 2 thin lenses separated by a distance?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I've found online that the formula for the effective focal length of 2 lenses separated by a distance is:

$$
\frac 1f=\frac 1{f_1}+\frac 1{f_2}-\frac d{f_1f_2}.
$$

However, I'd like to know how this formula is actually derived.  Also most places don't really define where f is measured from but I was able to find that it is the distance to the back principle plane which exists between the two lenses.  Based on this question [How is focal length defined for a two-lens system, separated by a distance $d$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247617/396423) the position of the BPP relative to the rear lens can be calculated by

$\delta$ = $\frac{-d}{n}$$\frac{f}{f_1}$

But I'm not sure how this formula is derived either.

Can Gullstrand's formula be derived geometrically from a ray diagram?  And how would you then figure out the location of the principle plane the resulting focal length is relative to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.